# Filter formula not including all values?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a `LET()`/`FILTER()` formula so that whatever value I select in my drop downs (`A22` and `B22`), it will quickly populate a table based on what's in the Master worksheet.

[image]

When I press enter in `A25`, you can see that it populates 4 rows based on criteria from Master worksheet:

[image]

but when I go to validate count of data, I see 7 rows:

[image]

Any ideas what I could be missing? It stops after the 4th returned row of data. Formula is:

```
=LET(
 _LastRow, COUNTA(Master!L:L),
 _FRng, Master!B3:INDEX(Master!B:B,_LastRow),
 _Comments,Master!D3:INDEX(Master!D:D,_LastRow),
 _CriteriaRange1, Master!L3:INDEX(Master!L:L,_LastRow),
 _CriteriaRange2, Master!M3:INDEX(Master!M:M,_LastRow),
 _Hstack, CHOOSE({1,2,3},_FRng,_Comments,_CriteriaRange1,_CriteriaRange2),
 FILTER(_Hstack,(_CriteriaRange1=A22)*(_CriteriaRange2=B22)))
```

Formula seems to think last row of Master is 1327, which it is not

[image]

edit: formula I tried for parent row logic:

```
=IFERROR(LET(
 _LastRow,MATCH(2,1/(Master!L:L<>"")),
 _FRng, Master!B3:INDEX(Master!B:B,_LastRow),
 _Comments,Master!D3:INDEX(Master!D:D,_LastRow),
 _CriteriaRange1, Master!L3:INDEX(Master!L:L,_LastRow),
 _CriteriaRange2, Master!M3:INDEX(Master!M:M,_LastRow),
 _ParentRow,Master!Q3:Index(Master!Q:Q,_LastRow),
 _Hstack, 
CHOOSE({1,2,3},_FRng,_Comments,_CriteriaRange1,_CriteriaRange2),
 _FILTER(IF(_ParentRow="Parent Row",_Hstack,(_CriteriaRange1=A22)* 
   (_CriteriaRange2=B22),""))),"")
```

Comment: Look for `Negotiating` whether it has leading or trailing white spaces or not. and let us know, dont see anything wrong with your formula yet!

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I just went in and no leading or trailing spaces. All of it's coming from a data validation list in Master sheet. Weird thing is why the first 4 rows populate but the other 3 are omitted. I figured it just wouldn't work, but its working for a select few?

Comment: Do check for the `Dan` name and is it happening for other names as well?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya it seems to be cutting off data for every name and status

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya could this be something with the indexing last row?

Comment: Try to check your `_LastRow` variable what does it returns

Comment: Hey @MayukhBhattacharya so I posted a pic in my post, it looks like it thinks lastrow of B is row 1327, which it is not

Comment: Could you try using `MATCH(2,1/(L:L<>""))` instead of the `COUNTA()` and let us know. If you add one excel file, I could have checked whats the problem

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya how can I attach an excel file? I have a test file I can send over

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya wait, the match function worked, thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented above and since OP found it to be working posting it as an answer.

Looking to get the last row using `MATCH()` function:

```
=LET(
 _LastRow, MATCH(2,1/(Master!L:L<>"")),
 _FRng, Master!B3:INDEX(Master!B:B,_LastRow),
 _Comments,Master!D3:INDEX(Master!D:D,_LastRow),
 _CriteriaRange1, Master!L3:INDEX(Master!L:L,_LastRow),
 _CriteriaRange2, Master!M3:INDEX(Master!M:M,_LastRow),
 _Hstack, CHOOSE({1,2,3},_FRng,_Comments,_CriteriaRange1,_CriteriaRange2),
 FILTER(_Hstack,(_CriteriaRange1=A22)*(_CriteriaRange2=B22)))
```

---

Suggested to use `MATCH()` instead of `COUNTA()` - **Reason** --> `COUNTA()` is excluding all the blank cells of Column `L:L` and was returning the total count of non blank cells, there fore using `MATCH()` function it returns the last row, since it is trying to find `2` the lookup value which it cant find from the array of `1/(MASTER!L:L<>"")` hence returns the `1` from the last row of the array using the approximate match!

### [image]

Adding `_ParentRow` as Criteria:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _LastRow,MATCH(2,1/(Master!L:L<>"")),
     _FRng, Master!B3:INDEX(Master!B:B,_LastRow),
     _Comments,Master!D3:INDEX(Master!D:D,_LastRow),
     _CriteriaRange1, Master!L3:INDEX(Master!L:L,_LastRow),
     _CriteriaRange2, Master!M3:INDEX(Master!M:M,_LastRow),
     _ParentRow,Master!Q3:INDEX(Master!Q:Q,_LastRow),
     _Hstack, CHOOSE({1,2,3},_FRng,_Comments,_CriteriaRange1,_CriteriaRange2),
    FILTER(_Hstack,(_CriteriaRange1=A22)*(_CriteriaRange2=B22)*(_ParentRow="Parent Row"),""))
```

---

Comment: Hey, quick question. I have a column Q in my Master worksheet and it has either a "-" or "Parent Row". I added a line to designate ParentRow just like I did Comments up above. I figured I could just add in that IF statement, but I'm getting stuck


`_FILTER(IF(_ParentRow="Parent Row",_Hstack,(_CriteriaRange1=A22)*(_CriteriaRange2=B22),""))),"")`

Comment: @Kolev_I_N no if same way as you did with `CriteriaRanges` and do you have any sample excel, can attach a cloud link, i wanted to see why the `COUNTA()` wasnt working

Comment: Here's a test file with sensitive data gone. https://file.io/O8nV2WRqNktT

Can you see how I would implement logic in the filter part where it only returns the data if column Q in Master  = "Parent Row"? I can update what I tried in post

Comment: @Kolev_I_N Just updated the answer, please check

Comment: @Kolev_I_N here is your **[Excel_Download_To_Check](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2cknPZGZU_WJXeSxE1?e=hEx1IZ)**